# Mysql left join: show rows based on another attribute from the joined table

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have following tables:

```
   Pools                         Members                             User
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id      name              id     pool_id     user_id              id      name
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       abc               1         1          101                101     test1
2       xyz               2         1          102                102     test2
                          3         2          105                105     test5
                          4         2          106                106     test6
```

When a user is logged in, he should view the list of those pools for which he is not a member e.g If user with id 101 is logged in, following result should be shown.

```
Pool              Members
xyz                2 members
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be you want to this

```
SELECT name AS Pool,
       count(pool_id) AS Members
FROM Pools
JOIN Members ON Pools.id=Members.pool_id
WHERE Pool.id NOT IN
    (SELECT pool_id
     FROM Members
     WHERE user_id=101)
GROUP BY Member.pool_id
```

Comment: The above query just shows one result e.g pool name with total count of members but I want list of all pools with total number of members against that pool.

Comment: Add `GROUP BY Member.pool_id` check my updated answer

Comment: Never forgot to accept/upvote when answer is helpful.